USA B2 visa implications of a prior refused UK visa application
I have had a UK tourist visa refusal 2 yrs ago. I have a 10 year USA B-2 visa and a recent Schengen visa. I wish to apply for UK visa again. However if I get refused will it impact my chances of getting a USA B-2 visa again?
I have travelled twice to the USA without overstay.


However if I get refused will it impact my chances of getting a USA B-2 visa again?

Not by itself, no.  In general, a visa refusal by another country can serve as a red flag to a visa officer, prompting further scrutiny, but your travel history in the Schengen area, and even more so your travel history in the USA, the country to which you are now reapplying, will carry greater weight in your favor than any negative impact of the UK refusal.

Thanx . I have visited us twice . So i hope i dont have an issue if i get refused by uk
